# Swift dictionary not working

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a great problem with a dictionary in a dictionary in Swift. I have some custom classes: **Team**, **Competition** and **Statistics**. **Team** and **Competition** conform to protocol **Hashable** and **Equatable**.

The dictionary looks like this: 
`[Team: [Competition: Statistics]]`.

Furthermore I have two "overall values": a **team** and a **competition**.

When I do the following: 
`println(dictionary[overallTeam]!)`

It prints the memory address of the competition and the statistics such you would expect. But, when I do the following: 
`println(dictionary[overallTeam]![overallCompetition])`

I get `nil` as output. I'm totally wondering about that since there is only 1 key in `dictionary[overallTeam]!` which has the same name as the `overallCompetition`. That means that the equatable sign `==` returns **true** and the hashValue is identical.

Please help, where would be the problem in this.

Here's the code:

In the `init()` method I do the following:

```
dictionary = [Team: [Competition: Statistics]]()
dictionary[overallTeam] = [Competition: Statistics]()
dictionary[overallTeam]![overallCompetition] = Statistics()
```

The code for printing is in a method called when launching the application:

```
println(overallCompetition.name) //"overallCompetition"
println(overallCompetition.hashValue) //some hashCode, e.g. 5
for item in dictionary[overallTeam]!.keys { //executed once
    println(item.name) //"overallCompetition"
    println(item.hashValue) //SAME hashCode, e.g. 5
    println(dictionary[overallTeam]![item]!.value) //prints the value expected
}
println(dictionary[overallTeam]) //prints some memory addresses
println(dictionary[overallTeam]![overallCompetition]) //nil
println(dictionary[overallTeam]![overallCompetition]!.value) //error: unexpectedly found nil
```

Just a general question: Dictionary keys are based on a hashValue, aren't they? Then **why** do two keys with the *same* hashValue not produce the *same* result???

Comment: Could you please post the code that does the set-up and the printing of the dictionary variable.

Comment: Your dictionary defines the inner dictionary as having a Statistics key, but the inner dictionary is initialized with a PlayerStatistics key and then the value is initialized as a Statistics object... Is Statistics a subclass of PlayerStatistics or is PlayerStatistics a subclass of Statistics because your code is kind of implying that both are subclasses of each other. Change the value type of the inner dictionary to Statistics and see if that works.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to change it, changed the names so that they're not that long here.

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot compare a string to a different object type and get consistent results, because the relation isn't reflexive. In other words, while you may have implemented Equatable to say your object == string, it is not the case that therefore string == object, which would break it.

Since you are indexing the array by string name then you are never going to find it with `overallCompetition`. Either store the second dictionary with `overallCompetition` as the values, or use the overallCompetition.name to extract the value.

Comment: I'm not comparing a string to an object - only comparing two strings of two objects

Comment: Your code suggests that 'overallCompetition' is an object type, and the code you have posted suggests that your dictionary stores keys by String. So your code either needs to have `overallCompetition.name` in its lookup, or you need to store the object as the key.

Comment: The key is a Team object in the outer dictionary and a Competition object in the inner one

Comment: Ah my bad, sorry. Does it work if you extract out the in-line expression `dictionary[overallTeam]!` first?